# Would tail block appending to file in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, file, file-io, io, linux-kernel

We have two processes:

1. Append to the log file
2. Tail the log file and send it to the centralised monitor

My concern is if the process 2 would block process 1 during reading the file? Is there any lock contention in kernel/disk driver here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two requests need to synchronize at the filesystem level (in the kernel). The writer blocks for some amount of time the reader by locking the inodes corresponding to the file. The actual performance penalty depends on the filesystem you are using and on the amount of data you are appending.

Here is a small experiment to verify this. We first create a program that opens a file, repeatedly seeks to the end of the file, and tries to read whatever it finds. At the same time we have a different process that appends continuously a single zero byte to the file.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2
  3 int main() {
  4         int i;
  5         char buf[8192];
  6         int fd = open("test", 'r');
  7         while (i<100000000) {
  8                 lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
  9                 read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
 10                 i++;
 11         }
 12 return 0;
 13 }
```

Now we create the "test" file in an ext4 filesystem and start appending:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1M count=1
while true ; do dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1 oflag=append; done
```

Running the program while appending:

```
time ./readfile    
real    1m24.393s
user    0m4.173s
sys     1m15.518s
```

While running without appending:

```
time ./readfile
real    0m30.480s
user    0m3.130s
sys     0m27.349s
```

As you can see, the reads are much slower when the file is being modified and the main difference is in the system time. This is consistent with the reader getting blocked while doing a system call due to concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My main concern is if the reader would block the appender.

Comment: Yes, the reader can also block the writer. Some synchronization is inherently required in filesystem to avoid accessing inconsistent metadata or data. I run the same experiment this time using: 

time dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1 count=10000000 oflag=append

I get the baseline performance for dd:
real    0m24.808s
user    0m0.865s
sys     0m23.842s

And when the readfile is running:
real    0m33.996s
user    0m1.116s
sys     0m31.751s

PS: there is a bug in the code (i needs to be initialized)